# Problems with a custom Vaadin JavaScript component overflowing into other components in the VerticalLayout

Tags: java, javascript, css, vaadin

I have a custom JavaScript component (placed in an VerticalLayout) that height grows dynamically with user input - similar to the stackoverflow edit fields with the preview beneath it.

The problem is that the "preview" overlaps with the content of components placed below the custom component when a certain size is reached. Imagine that the "preview" would move behind the tags field and submit button in stackoverflow when writing more than 4 lines.

The css for the JavaScript component doesn't contain any sizing information (beside width:100%) and neither does the VerticalLayout.

Question: **How do I specify in a Vaadin VerticalLayout that components should move down if the size of an earlier component is changed?**

Or do you have any other ideas how to solve this common situation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was an oversight with `.setStyleName("myComponentInstance");` that was used in the `ExampleView` for the custom component. When checking the ExampleView.css I found out that someone defined a specific size and height that interfered with the styling of the custom component itself - with very confusing results.

So, if you stumble into a similar situation while developing a JavaScript Vaadin component:

1. Remove the `myComponent.setStyleName("myComponentInstance")` in the using code to avoid all interference with your own styling.
2. Don't define the css `height` value but depend on the default sizing in the VerticalLayout component.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setSizeFull() on the VerticalLayout so it will grow on the contents add to it.

Comment: The VerticalLayout is already set to setSizeFull and it doesn't help. The problem is, that the position of the other components in the VerticalLayout seem to be fixed and won't change if one of the component changes.